# Vim and IPython

Tags: vim, ipython, jupyter, vi

I have remapped a key to copy and paste selected code from a split window to a second window in which IPython is running:

```
noremap <F5> Y<c-w>w<c-w>"*<Enter><c-w>p
```

It copy and paste without problem but I can't figure out how to execute the code  in IPython. When I press manually Enter it executes the code but I can't do it automatically (< CR> or < Enter > or < c-j > in my mapping result in inserting a new line, not executing the code).

I've searched everywhere on the web, it looks like it is how Ipython handles the input, as the regular python shell works as intended.

I use vim (mingw64) under windows, and python 3.6.8.

I would really appreciate any suggestion on how to do to.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If I decompose it in two keys it works:
1) noremap <F5> Y<c-w>w<c-w>"*

 2) tnoremap <F6> <CR><c-w>p

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on Linux. What happens when you use a different register? Like `noremap <F5>  "pY<c-w>w<c-w>"p<c-w>p`. (I don't need `<Enter>` at all.)

Comment: @Ralf It creates a new line, still doesn't execute the code for me ;(

Comment: @m.G What happens if you map it to f5 and f6 but then map <F4> to be <F5><F6>?